What's a good way to create a list of all installed applications on your computer alongside their respective icons?
I'm trying to create a list of all installed applications and their icons by looking through the Windows registry uninstall keys, but not all applications have a "DisplayIcon" key.
Here's the code going through the registry to find "DisplayName" and "DisplayIcon" subkeys:
def list_installed_apps_windows():
    uninstall_keys = [
        r"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall",
        r"SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall"
    ]

    installed_apps = {}

    for key in uninstall_keys:
        reg_key = None  # Initialize reg_key to None
        try:
            reg_key = winreg.OpenKey(winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, key)
            for i in range(winreg.QueryInfoKey(reg_key)[0]):
                subkey_name = winreg.EnumKey(reg_key, i)
                subkey = winreg.OpenKey(reg_key, subkey_name)
                try:
                    app_name = winreg.QueryValueEx(subkey, "DisplayName")[0]
                    # Attempt to get the DisplayIcon, if it exists
                    icon_path = None
                    try:
                        icon_path = winreg.QueryValueEx(subkey, "DisplayIcon")[0]
                    except FileNotFoundError:
                        icon_path = None

                    installed_apps[app_name] = icon_path
                except OSError:
                    # Handle the case where DisplayName does not exist
                    continue
                finally:
                    winreg.CloseKey(subkey)  # Ensure we close the subkey
        except OSError as e:
            # Log or print the error (optional)
            print(f"Error accessing registry key {key}: {e}")
            continue
        finally:
            if reg_key:  # Only close reg_key if it was successfully opened
                winreg.CloseKey(reg_key)  # Ensure we close the main key

    # Sort the installed_apps dictionary alphabetically by app_name
    sorted_installed_apps = dict(sorted(installed_apps.items()))

    return sorted_installed_apps


def list_installed_apps():
    os_name = platform.system()

    if os_name == "Windows":
        return list_installed_apps_windows()
    else:
        return {}


And this is how I use the list in my main window of a PyQt6 application:
installed_apps = list_installed_apps()
        for app_name, icon_path in installed_apps.items():
            if icon_path and os.path.exists(icon_path):
                icon = QIcon(icon_path)
            else:
                icon = QIcon()  # Default blank icon
            self.installed_apps_combobox1.addItem(icon, app_name)
            self.installed_apps_combobox2.addItem(icon, app_name)
            self.installed_apps_combobox3.addItem(icon, app_name)
            self.installed_apps_combobox4.addItem(icon, app_name)

And here's the result:

The problem is that most applications don't have a "DisplayIcon", I would say only about 5-10% of the ones installed on my computer. Basic applications like Google Chrome or Steam have their icons missing.
Is there something that can be improved with the provided code or is there some sort of an alternative approach I can take?
